# Change Outlook mailItem temporary

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, addin-express

When I modify or change any property in the mailItem, Outlook saves the changes permanently on exchange. For example, when I change the subject of a mail, then Outlook syncs the change with exchange. Is it possible to modify a mail temporarly, only for view purposes ?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, but as I mentioned outlook saves/syncs any changes I've made.
For example: mailitem.Subject = "MyTemporarySubject";. This modification will be immediately synced ord saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Outlook will not save changes unless Save is called. But it will prompt your save your changes if a message is closed by the user.

Most importantly, you need to rethink the problem you are trying to solve - it sure sounds like you want to display something different from what Outlook actually stores. You can attempt to display a different item entirely, or change (if possible) the way Outlook displays the data instead of temporarily modifying the item.

Comment: Okay. But can you give me an example how I could achieve this ? 
For example: I see a mail in my inbox with the subject: "Hello World".
How can I display "Hello Universe" insted of "Hello World" in my outlook explorer without modifying the mailItem ?

Comment: In an Explorer that lists all items i na folder? Or in an Inspector when you open the item?

Comment: I need Both. In my explorer and in an Inspector.

Comment: Northing you can do about the explorer - it can only display the real data coming from the folder contents table.